# How can I solve redirect issue?

Tags: google-sheets, gravity-forms-plugin

This is the error I get when I try to generate the client code token in google spreadsheet add-on for gravity forms:

[image]

Comment: This appears to be a Gravity Forms support issue. Have you asked there?

Comment: really it is an add on for gravity (google Spreadsheet Add on), and support is offered by https://webholics.org , so they are not answering me.

Comment: Sorry, I thought this was a Gravity Forms add-on; I see now it is an add-on that makes use of Gravity Forms. Still, I would be asking Webholics for support. In any event, When setting up, did you get the green sign saying that the Client Tone was authorised (as per KnowledgeBase/